# Constructing a diagonal matrix from vector of integers: function eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a vector of integers and I want to construct a diagonal matrix with vectos's element as diagonal entries of the matrix. For example: if vector is `1 2 3` the diagonal matrix would be:

```
1 0 0
0 2 0
0 0 3
```

The naive way to do it would be just iterate over it and set elements one by one. Is there no other direct way to do this in `eigen`. Also after constructing the diagonal I want to calculate the inverse(which is just reversing the diagonal entries) but there does not seem to be a way to do this too(directly, which would be optimized way too) in the library itself.

I have looked up the documentation of [diagonal matrices](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DiagonalMatrix.html#a47affd1a10b589811fc4828c1a2e0c6d) in `eigen` library but it seems like that there is no way .If I have missed something obvious while reading the documentation please point out.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you find a way to quickly generate the matrix from the vector, inverting it is rather simple: Invert the vector's elements and create the matrix from scratch.

Comment: @arne I did not want to get into floating point errors, if they may arise(I am not sure). So want eigen to handle everything. I guessed that would be easy.

Comment: The page you linked gives a 3D `DiagonaMatrix` constructor taking the 3 relevant coefficients as arguments. There's also a method to extract the diagonal vector out of such a matrix, which you could use to compute "by hand" the inverted vector and construct a new matrix with.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: It probably is, I just don't know anything about `eigen`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this part of the documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html#QuickRef_DiagTriSymm) you have quite a few options, the easiest one being

```
auto mat = vec.asDiagonal();
```

Comment: Correct documentation can be tricky to find sometimes. I did google search but this didn't show up. It may sound weird but any tricks/tips?

Comment: I used the query `diagonal matrix from vector eigen`, so no real tricks here :)

Comment: Documentation link is dead.

Comment: Seems to be because of a newer version of doxygen, I corrected the link.

Comment: for completeless: It is also possible to get a dense matrix out of the diagonal matrix: `auto mat = vec.asDiagonal().toDenseMatrix();`

Answer (score 3):

You should use proper types with Eigen, unless you really know what you're doing

```
//Create a 4x4 diagonal matrix from the vector [ 5 6 7 8 ]
Eigen::Vector4d vec;
vec << 5, 6, 7, 8;
Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, 4> mat = vec.asDiagonal();
```

Using auto is a really slippery slope where you typically have no idea what the compiler uses as the type, and coupled with Eigen, this is one of the common sources of tricky-to-find errors (see https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it the other way around, which allows you to *set super/subdiagonals as well*.

```
MatrixXd A = ...;
A.diagonal(0) = values_vector; //for 'main' diagonal
A.diagonal(1) = other_values; //for 1st super-diagonal
```

See [Eigen Matrix Diagonal() reference](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a8a13d4b8efbd7797ee8efd3dd988a7f7) (also has an example)